# Using onProgress in react-scroll-trigger

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the NPM package (https://github.com/ryanhefner/react-scroll-trigger) to handle some of my animations on a new website I am building. I'm using the

```
    onEnter
```

and

```
    onExit
```

just fine. However, I would like to use the

```
    onProgress
```

prop to trigger multiple animations in the window at different times, and change them as I scroll. I need them to be attached to the scroll position. But, being new to JS, I don't fully understand what the package has written as far as how to use the onProgress to tell my function what the value of the progress is. Can someone help me understand how I'm supposed to use this?

```
    ...

    const AppContainer = styled.div`
      width: 100%;
    `;

    const Section1 = styled.div`
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: lightgray;
    `;

    const Section2 = styled.div`
      width: 100%;
      height: 500px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    `;

    const Heading = styled.h1`
      font-size: 50px;
      color: #270d61;
      opacity: ${props => props.visible === true ? "1" : "0"};
      transition: opacity 5000ms;
    `;

    class App extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                visible: false,
            }
        };

        onProgress = () => {
            //some functions here
        };

        render () {
            return (
                <AppContainer>
                    <Section1/>
                    <Section2>
                        <Heading visible={this.state.visible}>
                            <ScrollTrigger onProgress={this.onProgress()}/>
                            What's Up?
                        </Heading>
                    </Section2>
                </AppContainer>
            )
        }
    }

    export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `<ScrollTrigger />` component is meant to wrap around content.. The `ScrollTrigger` is nothing more than a `div` that kicks off misc event depending upon where that `div` is at relative to the viewport.

Here is a little demo that should be useful for you... It shows how you can use the `onProgess`, `onEnter`, and `onExit` events (at a high level)..

[image: Edit crazy-rgb-0tqw5]

**Note:** I had to open the CodeSandbox window in a new tab for this to work half the time... [you can try this link](https://0tqw5.csb.app/) - if that doesn't work just open the Sandbox URL in a new tab..

Hope this helps!

***Code:***

```
export default class AppScroller extends Component {
  state = {
    cssworld: "",
    cssfadein: "",
    progress: 0
  };

  onEnterViewport = () => {
    console.log("entered");
    this.setState({
      cssworld: "world",
      cssfadein: "fadeInText"
    });
  };

  onExitViewport = () => {
    console.log("exited");
    this.setState({
      cssworld: "",
      cssfadein: ""
    });
  };

  onProgress = e => {
    this.setState({
      progress: e.progress.toFixed(2)
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { progress, cssworld, cssfadein } = this.state;

    return (
      <div
        style={{
          height: "2000px",
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center"
        }}
      >
        <ScrollTrigger
          style={{
            border: "2px solid green",
            height: "10%",
            width: "100%"
          }}
          onEnter={this.onEnterViewport}
          onExit={this.onExitViewport}
          onProgress={this.onProgress}
        >
          <div style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>
            <img
              alt="world"
              className={cssworld}
              style={{ width: "100px" }}
              src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Erioll_world_2.svg/256px-Erioll_world_2.svg.png"
            />
          </div>
          <div style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>
            <p className={cssfadein}>This is some text to fade in!</p>
          </div>
          <div
            style={{
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              position: "fixed"
            }}
          >
            Progress: {progress * 100}%
          </div>
        </ScrollTrigger>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

***CSS***

```css
.world {
  -webkit-animation: spin1 5s linear;
  -moz-animation: spin1 5s linear;
  -o-animation: spin1 5s linear;
  -ms-animation: spin1 5s linear;
  animation: spin1 5s linear;
  display: block;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin1 {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes spin1 {
  0% {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes spin1 {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin1 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.fadeInText {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  animation: fadein 5s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 5s; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-animation: fadein 5s; /* Opera */
}
@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  /* Firefox */
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein {
  /* Opera */
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: This helps a lot, thanks! Can you walk me through what this is doing exactly as far as what the .toFixed(2) does?

        onProgress = e => {
            this.setState({
              progress: e.progress.toFixed(2)
            });
          };

Comment: Absolutely! The `.toFixed(2)` will take a float and 'fix' it to X decimal points. For example, if I have `let myNumber = 1.991111111` and then I do `let myFixedNumber = myNumber.toFixed(2)` the value of `myFixedNumber` would be `1.99`.  It 'fixes' the value to 2 decimal points. When the `onProgress` method fires, the event contains an object with two properties - `progress` and `velocity` that are each 17 digit floats (which is the max amount of digits for a float in JS).. I just converted that long float into a more legible percentage. I have updated the CodePen to show the `onProgress` event